Changing object's material color using an attribute in Maya
I have a  sphere controled by a circle nurbs. I added a float attribute to the circle to change the sphere color but not sure how to do that using nodes
Not sure if this is the way to get it:
I tried decomposing rgb to hsv and back but no luck... Any idea?
Thanks

I'm afraid it's not possible. I got something similar using driven keys with a float attribute and changing the color values. The user can't choose directly a color but it's an approach to what I need
